# Tapestry5 form in a table with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, html-table, tapestry

I'm having a problem with tapestry5. I would like to make an ajax forms in a loop like [this one](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/formsinaloop). The problem is that even when I don't put the loop and only make a form inside a table with ajax, tapestry give me this exception:

> "Forms require that the request method be POST and that the t:formdata query parameter have values".

```
      <table>

            <t:zone t:id="zone" id="zone">
                <t:form zone="^">
                <label>email</label>
                <intput t:type="TextField" t:id="email" value="profile.email"/>

                <input t:type="submit" t:id="save" value="Save"/>
                </t:form>
            </t:zone>           
    </table>
```

The most strange thing is when I put the table inside the form, it works fine, but I need put it out. Someone knows what's happening?

Comment: Im not sure what you meant by ajax forms? If you dont want it to use it as a form where you click submit dont use the form. You can read all the values into parameters in tapestry even without the form

Comment: I want that in a table, when I press an edit button of that row, only that row changes to textfields and when I press save or cancel, the changes will be done or not. All with ajax.

Comment: This will produce invalid HTML. table/tr/td is valid, table/div/form is not???

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not completely sure why this exception is happening, you can solve it by using the  [AjaxFormLoop](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html) in stead. Check out the [example on the Jumpstart page](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/formsinaloopwithdeh).